# Can't find files older than 1 day

Tags: find

I want to find all files beginning by `backup*` older that 1 day in a folder.

I do:

```
find /home/mypc/backup* -mtime +1
```

But I am getting an empty list.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Related: [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92346/117037)

Comment: Has your computer suffered any recent strong bumps, or been affected by chemicals? Could be amnesia. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

From file system root dir:

```
sudo find / -name "backup*" -mtime +0
```

From user dir:

```
find ~/ -name "backup*" -mtime +0
```

**-mtime +0** matches any file whose mtime difference is at least 24 hours. Tf you want mtime to count calendar days, and not n-24 hour periods from now, use `-daystart`: `-daystart -mtime 0` is means today and `-daystart -mtime +0` means before today.

Also you can find only files with adding `-type f` or only dirs `-type d`.

Comment: It would also help to explain `find /home/mypc -name "backup*"` vs `find /home/mypc/backup*`